# Парсинг таблицы C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Я для себя поставил задачу (как практика, никогда не работал с парсингом сайтов) сделать парсер магазина. Магазин представлен в виде таблицы

```
ТОВАРЫ ДЛЯ ДОМА
Подушка | 12шт | 400руб
Стул    | 3шт  | 330руб
Диван   | 1шт  | 1200руб
```

Вот мой код

```
using (HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest())
        {
            string html = req.Get("https://site.com/").ToString();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//table");
            List<ReadOnlyCollection<string>> Elements = new List<ReadOnlyCollection<string>>();
            HtmlNodeCollection nodes = table.SelectNodes("//td");
            int value = 0;
            do
            {
                List<string> tableRow = new List<string>
                {

                    nodes[value++].InnerText.Trim(),
                    nodes[value++].InnerText.Trim(),
                    nodes[value++].InnerText.Trim(),
                    nodes[value++].InnerText.Trim()
                };
                Elements.Add(tableRow.AsReadOnly());
            } while (value < nodes.Count);

            foreach (ReadOnlyCollection<string> cls in Elements)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} \r\n {1} \r\n {2}", cls[0], cls[1], cls[2]);
            }
        }
```

Как можно спарсить в отдельные переменные название категории, и сам товар со всеми столбцами?
На пример вывести все товары где количество не меньше 5 шт и не дороже 500рублей
Спасибо. Может LINQ как то использовать? Ибо мой код работает не корректно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для удобства создайте класс с нужными вам свойствами

```
public class TableItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Тогда заполнить коллекцию можно так.

```cs
List<TableItem> elements = new List<TableItem>();

for (int i = 0; i <= nodes.Count - 4; i += 4)
{
    elements.Add(new TableItem
    {
        Name = nodes[i].InnerText.Trim(),
        Count = int.Parse(nodes[i + 1].InnerText.Replace("шт", "")),
        Price = int.Parse(nodes[i + 2].InnerText.Replace("руб", "")),
    });
}
```

Сразу числовые значения лучше распарсить в числовые типы.

Тогда можно будет более-менее удобные Linq запросы

> На пример вывести все товары где количество не меньше 5 шт и не дороже 500рублей

```cs
foreach (TableItem item in elements.Where(x => x.Count >= 5 && x.Price <= 500))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, item.Name, item.Count, item.Price));
}
```

Comment: спасибо. А как получить категорию товара? В ней ведь нет столбцов, получается что выдаст ошибку?

Comment: "ТОВАРЫ ДЛЯ ДОМА" это идет как отдельной строкой

Comment: @GRAMOTEYTV нужно правильный `string category = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//...").InnerText` сделать. Я же не вижу ваш HTML.

Comment: ага понял, еще раз спасибо

Comment: А подскажи еще пожалуйста. Вот я хочу вывести все строки, в которых `td` больше 3 шт
`HtmlNodeCollection table = htmlNodes.SelectNodes("//tr/td");` Как использовать `Where` что только не перепробовал. То тип не правильно приводится, то вообще нет такого свойства как Count

Comment: @GRAMOTEYTV сначала выбрать просто `//tr`, запустить цикл по ним, потом внутри каждой итерации цикла выбарать `//td`, проверять `Count` и если меньше, то `continue;`. Это должно быть просто.

Comment: Я попробовал вот так 
`HtmlNodeCollection table = (HtmlNodeCollection)htmlNodes.SelectNodes("//tr").GroupBy(x => x.SelectNodes("//td").Count > 3);` Каждый `tr` я представил в виде группы и если в этой группе `td` больше 3, то пусть записывает в коллекцию, но выдает `Необработанное исключение: System.InvalidCastException: Не удалось привести тип объекта`

Comment: @GRAMOTEYTV `GroupBy` здесь не подходит, потому что это тупо коллекция `tr` нод, линейный список.

Comment: понял, я думал что тут такое возможно, недавно начал ковырять LINQ

Comment: @GRAMOTEYTV но если очень хочется, то `var nodes = htmlNodes.SelectNodes("//tr").Select(tr => tr.SelectNodes("//td")).Where(x => x.Count > 3).SelectMany(x => x)`